# how to deploy an express/react to apache

Tags: reactjs, apache, express, deployment

I have a project that has a react app inside the express server. I would like to deploy it to my own CentOS/Apache server. How i can i do this? I've done some google and seen AWS things, and i just doesn't seem like it needs to be that complicated. I really just want it to run on my server so i can show other people and do testing. I do have a spare computer to create another nginx server if needed (or whatever else you guys reccomend).

Ive also added this code to my server.js file. which aparently isnt enough. Thanks for all help!

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    //SET STATIC FOLDER
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(_dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    })
}
```

Comment: What do you want, to test your express-react app or to learn to deploy a node app in an apache server?

Comment: to deploy a express node app on apache